# Rotational spectroscopy application of different equations

Tags: physical-chemistry, spectroscopy

So we were given two problems and I don't understand why one was solved one way, and another was solved another way

Estimate the bond length of 12C16O (pure rotational spectrum) given J''=3 (15.356 cm-1) and J'=9 (38.356)

To solve we used

$12B = (38.356 - 15.365)=1.916$

to solve for B and then used to determine the bond length.

In another problem we are told that the J=3 to J=4 transition for a diatomic occurs at 0.50 cm-1. What is the J=6 to J=7 transition for this molecule assuming rigid rotor.

In this problem We used

$E(rotation) = Bh[J'(J'+1) - J''(J''+1)]$

Which when solved/rearranged becomes

$E(rotation) = 2BhJ'$

Which can be rearranged to solve for B, because we know the energy as a wavenumber. This B is then used to calculate the transition wavenumber for 6 to 7 transition.

I am lost as to why in the first one we can simply assume each transition is 2B apart and so 6 transitions would be 12B and solve whereas in the second we cannot make this assumption.

Comment: The transitions themselves aren't 2B, they spaced apart by 2B. In the first case, you had two transitions, so you could determine B by their spacing. In the second case, you only know the location of one, but B is also related to the energy of a single transition by the equation given.

Comment: In the second case, once you have B, you can just use the separation to solve for the energy of the 2nd transition. They happened to use a different equation but that doesn't mean you couldn't use the same equation in both cases.